# Sending Intent from BroadcastReceiver class to currently running activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I have a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. On receiving a SMS, I would like to pass information to my main activity class to display the text in a box (Append, if already text is present).

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("updatedString","Hello");
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  private TextView results;
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.append(extras.getString("updatedString"));
        }

}
```

I have only one activity class (`MainActivity.java`). However When i do this I get an exception Unable to pause Activity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three ways:
1) You can define your broadcast inside your `MainActivity` like this:
in `onCreate()`

```
registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_RECIEVED));
```

and define smsReciver in `MainActivity`

```
private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //you can update textBox here
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);  
    }
};
```

define a runnable to update UI

```
private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        update();
    }
};
```

and update method

```
private void update(String text) {
    textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + text);
}
```

2) Register a receiver between your Activity and BroadCastReceiver

3) Start your Activity with new Intent to update current open Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Key", "text");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE :**
explain method 2
 MainActivity.class

in `onResume()`

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SmsReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION));
```

in `onDestroy()`

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

local broadCast (broadcastReceiver, in MainActivity.class)

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUI(intent);
    }
};
private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
    String text = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + text);
}
```

SmsReceiver.class
global attribute

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "your.package.name.displayevent";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
Context context;
```

in `onReceive()`

```
handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);

this.context = context;//you can retrieve context from onReceive argument

this.intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
```

define two method

```
private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        display();
    }
};

private void display() {
    intent.putExtra("key", text);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: How do i Send the message from SmsReceiver Class. I have written the following code:
Intent i = new Intent("SMS_RECIEVED");

                i.putExtra("updatedString",str);

                LocalBroadcastManager mgr= LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);

                mgr.sendBroadcast(i);

Comment: which way you want to use? 1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: you don't need to sendBroadCast ,receiver define in your MainActivity so you can simply edit textBox in your onReceive. I update answer to guid you

Comment: I tried your 3rd method and it worked. However, everytime a message comes a new activity is being called. Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: try to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); to your intent

Comment: where is the context defined in context.sendBroadcast ?

Comment: the function display wont be able to access the variable context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80515/discussion-between-user1692342-and-mhp).

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as below.

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override 

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    { 
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("updatedString","Hello");            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(i);
    } 
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  private TextView results;
  @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.append(extras.getString("updatedString"));
        } 

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
      //handle your intent here.Note this will be called even when activity first created.so becareful to handle intents correctly.
    }

}
```